# How can I make postgres run in the background all the time?

Tags: macos, postgresql

I need to go into my Postgres config folder and type:

```
postgres -D .
```

To run my database. If I do not do this I cannot access my databases with Rails. On my other computer I never had to do this though. How can I make postgres run in the background all the time?

Comment: Which operating system are you using?

Comment: My OS is OS X Yosemite